# Checking for valid IP for connection with NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I currently have an ap that attempts to open a webview based on certain servers I am communicating with.

However, I allow the user the capability to type in their own server IPs in case both the iphone/ipad and server(or other device) are not on the same network.  However, I am attempting to use NSURLConnection to detect if I can open a connection with the given IP however NSURLConnection never returns an error, even if the server address(or even a random web address) is completely bogus.

the .h

```
        @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate> {
```

the relevant code in the .m

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
        dev_ip = @"http://www.asdfasfdfa.com/";
        //dev_ip = (random ip)
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dev_ip]];

        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (conn) {
            NSLog(@"Connection established");    

        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Device at designated IP"]

                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
      }
```

this if/else always outputs 'Connection established.'  Is this something NSURLConnection should not be used for?  If so, what can I use to detect devices at given IP's for connectivity.  I need to stop the user from attempting to connect to bad IP's so whats the best method in doing so?

Comment: You've only created an object to represent the connection. You should not consider the connection itself established yet.

Comment: I figured something like this was happening, but all the delegates I know of for NSURLConnection apply to receiving data back.  Which in most cases would never happen.  So how do I check for an established connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSURLConnection, when used with delegation, will call delegate methods when it connects, fails to connect and receive data. You should look into NSURLConnectionDelegate.

Here's a quick example:

```
    // In your .h

    @interface MyClass : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

    @end
```

*EDIT* You actually need both delegates.

---

```
    // In your .m

    @implementation MyClass

    - (void)myMethodToConnect {

         NSString *dev_ip = @"http://74.125.137.101"; // Google.com

         NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dev_ip]];

         NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

        switch ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]) { // Edited this!
            case 200: {
                NSLog(@"Received connection response!");
                break;
            }
            default: {
                NSLog(@"Something bad happened!");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting. Error: %@", error);
    }
    @end
```

Also, just throwing it out there too, you don't necessarily have to use an asynchronous call. You can send a synchronous call which doesn't require you to implement a delegate. Here's how:

```
    NSString *dev_ip = @"http://www.asdfasdfasdf.com/";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dev_ip]];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *connectionData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

You can check the response value and errors.

Comment: I'll try the 'did receive response' delegate.  In your switch statement, response is of type NSURLResponse not of type Int for your switch.  Would a conversion alter the data any?  I assume the 200 value is specific for successful connections?

Comment: To get the data that's actually coming through, you need to use didReceiveData method. I can include it in the code too if you'd like.

Comment: I am familiar with the didReceiveData delegate.  I just needed to find out how to detect a good connection.

Comment: You might want to check for the 300 range codes in didReceiveResponse, which should represent a successful call as well (redirects). Everything in the 400 and 500 range should be errors.

Comment: Well, as of right now, I'm never going into the didReceiveResponse delegate method when the code above is executed....  i'm never being returned anything

Comment: Is your class implementing the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol?

Comment: Ha, apparently, there's a new delegate called "NSURLConnectionDataDelegate". Add it to the list of implemented protocols. That should do the trick. I'll edit my response.

Comment: By NSURLConnectionDelegate do you mean didReceiveResponse?

Comment: No, they moved didReceiveResponse from NSURLConnectionDelegate to NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. That's why it's never being called. They kept didFailWithError in NSURLConnectionDelegate, that's why you need both.

Comment: Yeah, something about this still isn't working, even with the delegates declared.  didReceiveResponse is never getting accessed

Comment: Can you post more code? Post your class declaration from your .h and your implementation of the code above.

Comment: I can, but what I listed is pretty much it.  The user is selecting a value in a list and when they do I initiate a connection to the value stored in dev_ip (an IP address).  I need a way to detect if the IP is valid and a connection can be made.  That's all thats going on here.

Comment: One thing to note, did return with error always returns with an error, even with a valid IP....

Comment: It's an NSURLConnection. It'll try to connect using HTTP. If there's no web server there, it'll fail. Try putting http://www.stackoverflow.com in dev_ip.

Comment: connecting to google.com in dev_ip has the didReturnWithError delegate say Error connecting. Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x6d361c0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=google.com, NSErrorFailingURLKey=google.com, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x6d36250 "unsupported URL"}   THis is consistent with all of my connections....

Comment: don't forget the "http://". Sorry, my comment had the http part cut off by StackOverflow :D

Comment: Ok, but this means it wont work with IP's right?  Which is really, what I need to check.  I guess I'll need to add the http:// on them

Comment: You can use http:// 127.0.0.1 for example. As long as the endpoint has a web server running, you're good to go, name or IP.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an IP address for the request. Let me know if that works for ya.

Comment: This seems to be working so far. Thanks sgmerain06.  Now I just need to figure out a way to know if the device that exists is the device I want it to be.  But that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way to test whether a server is valid or not. The [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class provides good API for this purpose.