# iOS HTTP POST method , connection confirmation

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

I'm trying to make a basic app that takes in a persons details and posts it on a private server. My URL is kept blank for now, If I use the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and use `didFailWithError`, it works saying there's no connection but when I try the `NSLog` method it says

> "connection is made"

for some reason. This is my code

```
- (void) saveData{
NSString *name = self.NameTextField.text;
NSString *phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberTextField.text;
NSString *age = self.ageTextField.text;
NSString *email = self.emailTextField.text;

//Define the URL
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@""];

//Initialize a request from the URL
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

//Specify that it will be a post request.
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// This is how we set header fields
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *DataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&phonenumber=%@&age=%@&email=%@",name,phoneNumber,age,email];

//Change your requests HTTPBody property
NSData *requestBodyData = [DataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;


// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.connection = conn;
if(self.connection){
    NSLog(@"Connection is made");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Connection is not made");
}
[self.connection start];
}
```

Do inform if theres any other mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that `if (self.connection)` is doing is checking to see if it's `nil` it's not actually checking to see if a connection has been made you do that at `[self.connection start];`. So essentially:

```
if (self.connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connection is made");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection is not made");
}
```

is the exact same as

```
if (self.connection != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Connection is made");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection is not made");
}
```

And `self.connection` is not `nil` because you assign `conn` to it which has been initialized. This can be seen in the two lines below from your code.

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.connection = conn;
```

What you could do if you are wanting to check whether the connection was successful or not is check the `HTTP Status` code in `didReceiveResponse:` (Code obtained from [Checking for valid IP for connection with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608701/checking-for-valid-ip-for-connection-with-nsurlconnection))

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    switch ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]) {
        case 200: {
            NSLog(@"Received connection response!");
            break;
        }
        default: {
            NSLog(@"Something bad happened!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**OR** if it's just to see whether you can or not you could implement the [Reachability code that Apple supplies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or use another open source version.

Comment: Can you please explain how does the switch case work? Does it always send 200 if the connection was made?

Comment: No what happens is if `response statusCode` returns `200` Which means the connection was successful it will jump to case `200` and do whatever code you have in there up to the `break` If the `statusCode` isn't `200` it will run the default. You can implement code for the different HTTP Status codes that get returned. Here's a list of the different codes that get returned http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and here's a link that gives a good example of switch case statements http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement

Comment: Oh alright, so basically it does send 200 when connection is successful. Thanks a ton, please explain what this code exactly mean.
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: You're setting the content-type (Or MIME type as they are also known as) of the request that you are making as json. So your request is expecting json data to be sent and it is expecting it to be encoded in a charset of utf-8. Here's a link that might give a better description of it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks whether the self.connection variable is not null, which it's not since the alloc init seems to have executed successfully. i.e the object is created and that is what you are checking, whether it does what you want is a different story.

Comment: Its initWithRequest, if the request has an empty URL, it still initializes it?

Comment: Yes! 'alloc init' and 'new' initialise the object. The reason is that they all inherit from NSObject so even if the init is not implemented in a specific class it will fall-back to the parent object. So the pointer will not be null and the conditional will pass its test.